# Continuous and open image of a Polish space

Tags: gn.general-topology

Suppose that we have a continuous open and closed  surjection $f\colon X\to Y$  of a Polish space $X$ to $Y.$ The closeness of $f$ implies that $Y$ is a metric space.

But i do not know how to use that $f$ is continuous and open to prove that $Y$ is Polish, is there some result that implies this?

Comment: Well, showing $Y$ is separable is pretty straightforward, just using continuity.  Let $E$ be a countable dense subset of $X$ and consider $f(E)$.  What is $f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(E)}\right)$?  Now note that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: The problem was not the separability, i was stuck in trying to prove that $Y$ is completely metrizable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following list of results will show that $Y$ is Polish.

- It is basic that the continuous image of a separable space is separable.
- Also basic is that the open image of a first-countable space is first-countable.
- Recall the Hanai-Morita-Stone Theorem:

  > Let $X$ be a metrizable space, and let $f : X \to Y$ be a closed continuous surjection. Then the following are equivalent.
  >
  > 1. $Y$ is metrizable.
  > 2. $Y$ is first-countable.
  > 3. $\partial f^{-1} \{ y \}$ is compact for each $y \in Y$ (where $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of $A$).
- (The two previous results imply that that the closed-and-open image of a metrizable space is metrizable.)
- It is a result of I.A. Vaĭnšteĭn (see Problem 4.5.13(e), p.293, in Engelking's *General Topology*, revised and completed ed.) that the metrizable closed image of a completely metrizable space is completely metrizable.

Comment: Is it true that if we only require $f$ open and $Y$ metric, then $Y$ is Polish?

Comment: @HectorPinedo Yes, that would also work. (It is a result of Hausdorff that the metrizable open continuous image of a completely metrizable space is completely metrizable. This is also an exercise in Engelking.)

Comment: You mean Excercise 5.5.8 (d), in page 341 right?